# Array of 15 elements with possibility of entering specific number at a specific location?

Tags: java

I need an array of 15 elements with random numbers (1-15). I should enter a value at a specific location, but the values after my selected location should go on by one location. ex: I have 
1 12 3 8 9 3 5 4 4 10 3 7 7 2 1 and I want to insert the number "5" at location 3 and now I should have 1 12 **5** *3 8 9 3 5 4 4 10 3 7 7 2* .

You have an idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ArrayList......or use more than one array.

Comment: `"You have an idea?"` -- yes, use an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ArrayList` as suggested in the comments. When you have to use a array you can take something like

```
for (int i = array.length - 2; i >= position; i--)               
    array[i+1] = array[i];
array[position] = value;
```

with `position` the index of the array you want to change and `value` the value to insert.